# Unexpected `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type` error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating chess game and am getting Typescript errors that I don't understand.

The errors occur in this class method:

```js
clickEvent (e: MouseEvent): void {
    const coordinates: ClientRect = this.chessBoard.getBoundingClientRect();
    const xCoord: number = e.clientX - coordinates.left;
    const yCoord: number = e.clientY - coordinates.top;
    const findColumn: number = Math.trunc(xCoord / this.squareSize);
    const findRow: number = Math.trunc(yCoord / this.squareSize);

    for (const figure of this.pieces) {
        if (figure.row === findRow && figure.column === findColumn) {
            this.chessBoard.draggable = true;
            this.chessBoard.ondragstart = (e) => e.dataTransfer?.setDragImage(figure.image, this.squareSize / 2, this.squareSize / 2);
            this.chessBoard.ondrag = (e) => {
                figure.newSteps?.forEach((step: IStep) => {
                    step.item = this.pieces.find(f => f.row === step.row && f.column === step.column);
                    (step.item && step.item.color !== figure.color) || !step.item ? this.highlight(step.row, step.column) : null;
                });
                this.newStepsArr = figure.steps || [];
            }
            this.chessBoard.ondragend = (e) => {
                this.newSquare(figure.row, figure.column);
                const squareCoords: ClientRect = this.chessBoard.getBoundingClientRect();
                const dragCoordX: number = Math.trunc((e.clientX - squareCoords.left) / this.squareSize);
                const dragCoordY: number = Math.trunc((e.clientY - squareCoords.top) / this.squareSize);

                figure.row = dragCoordY;
                figure.column = dragCoordX;

                const correctStep: IStep = figure.steps?.find((step: IStep) => step.row === figure.row && step.column === figure.column);
                if (!correctStep || (correctStep.item && correctStep.item.color === figure.color)) {
                    figure.row = figure.steps[0].row;
                    figure.column = figure.steps[0].column;
                }
                this.newStepsArr && this.newStepsArr.slice(1).forEach((step: IStep) => this.newSquare(step.row, step.column, step.item && step.item.image));
                figure.newSteps(figure.row, figure.column);
                this.newSquare(figure.row, figure.column, figure.image);

                this.chessBoard.draggable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant interface declaration:

```js
export interface IPiece {
    id: number,
    column: number,
    row: number,
    color: TColors,
    name: TName,
    image?: HTMLImageElement,
    steps?: IStep[],
    make?(row: number, column: number): void,
    newSteps?(row: number, column: number): void,
}
```

And these are the errors I am getting:

```
figure.newSteps?.forEach - Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '(row: number, column: number) => void'. ts(2339)

figure.row = figure.steps[0].row; - Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)
```

Will be so thankfull for your help!

Comment: create snippet please

Comment: You'll get more help with a jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/typescript

Comment: Generally it is expected that you post one question per... question. Listing out your compiler errors and asking people to fix your code isn't really the purpose of this site. What have you tried so far to solve these issues? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The answer is in your not so good question. Its clearly stated in the error log whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There errors are telling you exactly what's wrong! Listen to them!

```
figure.newSteps?.forEach - Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '(row: number, column: number) => void'. ts(2339)
```

According to your `IPiece` interface, `newSteps` is a function type with the signature `(row: number, column: number): void`. Functions do not have a `forEach` method (unless you add one). Obviously you are referring to [the *forEach* defined for Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). So you either have a basic logic problem or a typo, e.g. perhaps you meant:

```
figure.steps?.forEach
```

because `IPIece.steps` is an Array.

Likewise, the second error is correct as well. On the line

```
figure.row = figure.steps[0].row;
```

both `figure.steps` could be `undefined` (you declared `steps` in `IPiece` with a `?`) and `figure.steps[0]` could be `undefined` as well (e.g. if it is an empty array). You have not checked for either condition prior to this line.